# "Hidden" columns in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to make a custom list for inquiries, where users will fill in some information such as "Name", "Reason" etc. When they've finished filling in the information and added the item, the administrator will then go through the item, and fill in some new columns that the user hasn't been able to fill in.

I hope you understand me, otherwise you're more than welcome to ask questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SharePoint designer 2007, you can use the SPSecurityTrimmedControl who enable you to show/hide form field (or site action...).

Syntax :

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="ManageLists" runat="server"> 
    WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_HIDE_HERE
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

For the PermissionsString, all values [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using.

Apparently there was some errors in the template that our Sharepoint site is using. Therefore I made a new ASPX page and placed a custom list in it. This allowed me to change the fields without any errors occuring. I used the PermissiongString to hide the fields I didn't want the users to change in. When finished I copy/paste the code into the body of the original NewForm and EditForm. Probably not the easiest way, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use SharePoint Designer. You will create custom new and edit forms. This way when the user fills in the new form, only certain fields will appear. Then when the administrator edits the item using the edit form, they will have access to more fields.

Please see this [link](http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/how-to-customize-edit-forms-in_22.html) for more information.

Try making a copy of the form you wish to edit by copying and pasting to the same folder. Then click on the web part for the form and the code above will highlight . Look for tags IsVisible and change it from "true" to "false". This will hide the default form. Do not delete the original form.

Click on the web part in the design view then press your right arrow. This will move the cursor to right after the web part but still within the web part zone. Go to the Insert menu, select SharePoint Controls then Custom List form. A small dialog window will appear, select the list name from the first drop down, then select the content type from the second drop down. Finally select which form you want to insert, New, Edit or Display. Click OK. The new form will be displayed under the default form, and you will then see all of the fields in order and you can add or remove as you like.

Comment: When I reach step 5 I get the following error: "URL-adress ../../../_catalogs/masterpage is invalid"

When continueing, it shows my page, but with quite a lot of errors. Also I don't understand step 6: "Delete one web part which is already there into page and add click on Insert SharePoint Controls  -> Custom List Form."

Should I mention that I can't click into the containerwindow, because it just shows a circle with a red X in it?

Comment: Without doing step 5 I don't think you can do step 6. Try making a copy of the form you wish to edit. I'll add some description to my original answer

Comment: Thank you very much, but my primary problem is that I keep getting the error: "URL-address ../../../_catalogs/masterpage is invalid" when I open the webpage in Sharepoint Designer. I've tried searching the web, but can't find anyone else that has encountered the problem. Have you heard about it before?

Comment: Does this link help? http://www.dlocc.com/articles/sharepoint-masterpage-is-invalid-error-solution/

Answer (score 1):

If one did not want to edit the pages, couldn't one use Jquery to hide the fields? I have done this with SPservices. to check the user credentials if you will and then if matched display the hidden fields... all this is done from a web part...just a thought...I actually learned something great today.. great replies.